# DataSet Fill() method slow every time

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, performance, dataset

I have created a datagrid and filter for that datagrid. A filter including two dropdown and each and every dropdown change calls an AJAX function to fetch new data to the datagrid from the database. It is a large database but the SP I am calling only get about 1 seconds to fetch data. But when I debugged the code the Fill() method of the dataset gets infinite time to fill method. I am calling the same function each and every dropdown change. You can check it with the code below.

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=False, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Shared Function LoadCases(Id As String, statusId As Integer, severityId As Integer) As List(Of XCases)
    Try
        Dim dsCasesDataset As New DataSet
        Dim pCases As New List(Of XCases)
        connString = AppSettings("conALSQL")
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
            Using SqlCommand As New SqlCommand("get_cases", conn)
                SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrganizationId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Id
                SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@statusId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = statusId
                SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@severityId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = severityId
                conn.Open()
                Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand)
                    da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 300
                    ' Fill dataset
                    da.Fill(dsCasesDataset)
                End Using
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

        For Each dataRow As DataRow In dsCasesDataset.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim pcase As New XCases
                 'Fill data to object
            pCases.Add(pcase)
        Next
        dsCasesDataset.Clear()
        Return platformCases
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try

End Function
```

I am using another version of the same function to fetch data from a bigger table but it runs without any issue and it is fast. I tried SQLDataReader also. It also has the same issue. Could someone help me to find what I am getting wrong?

This is the AJAX jquery function I am calling

```
$("#ddlStatus").on("change", function () {
            statusId = $("#ddlStatus").val() == null ? 0 : $("#ddlStatus").val()
            severityId = $("#ddlSeverity").val() == null ? 0 : $("#ddlSeverity").val() 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: window.location.pathname + "/LoadCases",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ Id: targetId, statusId: statusId, severityId: severityId }),
                success: function (Ddata) {
                    data = Ddata.d;
                    //refill the grid
                    if (data.length == 0) {
                        casesgrid.datagrid.loadData(data);
                        $(".dvNoDataError").css({ "display": "block" });
                    } else {
                        casesgrid.datagrid.loadData(data);
                        $(".dvNoDataError").css({ "display": "none" });
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                }
            });
        })
```

Comment: Never, EVER have a `Catch` block that contains only `Throw ex`. If all you're going to do is rethrow then why are you catching the exception in the first place? If you do rethrow, just use `Throw` rather than `Throw ex` or else you're truncating the call stack and losing useful information.

Comment: "dataset gets infinite time to fill".  Are you saying that the `Fill` method never returns?

Comment: It fills but getting about 3 mins each time

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you for the information. I removed ex by the way

Comment: How many records does it retrieve in that 3 minutes?

Comment: @jmcilhinney even for 1 record, it gets 3 mins. But the db call only gets about 1sec. The other function I mentioned in the question before fetch and fill the datagrid in 5 seconds with 300 rows of data.